# how to add values to a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model that has a field called  `who_can_see` and I don't know how to add data to this filed nor the type of data (dictionary, array...)

```
#modles.py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
#
    who_can_see = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tweet_user', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

- you can see here where i add the  , I am trying to `who_can_see= [author, payload["who_can_see"]]` so I expected the field `who_can_see` to be an array but when I make the `POST` request i got `500` error

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_book(request):
    print({"request.data": request.data})
    payload = request.data
    user = request.user
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(id=payload["author"])
        book = Book.objects.create(
            title=payload["title"],
            description=payload["description"],
            added_by=user,
            author=author,
            # who_can_see= [author, payload["who_can_see"]]  # 
        )
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return JsonResponse({'books': serializer.data}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something terrible went wrong'}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create the book and then add the `who_can_see` property. Like the example on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

You are almost good in your case. It would look like :

```
def add_book(request):
    print({"request.data": request.data})
    payload = request.data
    user = request.user
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(id=payload["author"])
        book = Book.objects.create(
            title=payload["title"],
            description=payload["description"],
            added_by=user,
            author=author,
        )
        book.who_can_see.add(author) 
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return ...
```

EDIT : I realized that your model is not coherent with your view. Why do you link `who_can_see` to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and not `Author` ? According to your view, your model should be :

```
who_can_see = models.ManyToManyField(Author,related_name='tweet_user', blank=True)
```

Comment: if you note `# who_can_see= [author, payload["who_can_see"]]  # ` am I'm trying to add many users `payload["who_can_see"]` not only the author but also other users that came with the `request.data`

Comment: That is not working : you have to get the object Author before by doing a query with the id.

Comment: I tried this `book.who_can_see.add(author.id, 2,3])` and it worked but `book.who_can_see.add(author.id, payload["who_can_see"])` this don't work because return an array, how to make it return just numbers like that, can I make it a string and then convert it to numbers with comma `,`

Comment: The problem is with `payload["who_can_see"]` : you need to convert that to a list of integer. I suppose it is currently a string or a list of string